# Magento 2: Has anyone been able to successfully use Paypal payments pro on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment-methods, paypal, paypal-express

I have a client that has been using `paypal` payments pro for `magento 1` for a long time. It finally came time to upgrade platforms to `magento 2`and after building out the website and migrating all the data I'm unable to get payment pro worked. At all. There's not really any errors either, all that happens is when you try to checkout with a credit card is a message pops up saying `"Error occurred on the server. Please try again"`. Nothing in the logs, either. Just that.

I was wondering if anyone out there was actually able to make this solution work.

Comment: can you check system.log ?

Comment: I checked but I don't see anything relevant to this there.